# Extra space above boxed multi-line equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, boxes, framed

Well, this question is not new. It was asked back in 2007 in [texhax](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2007-August/008909.html), and [answered](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2007-August/008910.html) at the same time.

However, I couldn't apply the patch as mentioned in the answer, so I decided to ask it here. Consider this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\begin{align*}
    &H(x) \colon \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Select a random $|x|$-bit prime $q$.} \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Let } r \in_R \mathbb{Z}^*_q \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Output } \langle r, r^{h(x)} \bmod q \rangle
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

It generates something like this:

[image: Output with an extra line]

As you can see, there's an extra empty line above H(x).

How can I remove it?

Comment: Please always add a [full but minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. I had issues with the `\mathbb` macro because I didn't know the package which defines it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
    &H(x) \colon \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Select a random $|x|$-bit prime $q$.} \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Let } r \in_R \mathbb{Z}^*_q \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Output } \langle r, r^{h(x)} \bmod q \rangle
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

You can even make it a colorbox with

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{yellow}]{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set `\abovedisplayskip` to `0pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\begin{align*}
    &H(x) \colon \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Select a random $|x|$-bit prime $q$.} \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Let } r \in_R \mathbb{Z}^*_q \\
    &\qquad \textnormal{Output } \langle r, r^{h(x)} \bmod q \rangle
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use `align` for this, which is a task for `tabular`

```
\fbox{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}l}
  \makebox[2em][l]{$H(x)$:}\\
  & Select a random $|x|$-bit prime $q$. \\
  & Let $r \in_R \mathbb{Z}^*_q$ \\
  & Output $\langle r, r^{h(x)} \bmod q \rangle$
  \end{tabular}}
```

and you don't even need to guess the width of the alignment.