# Spurious space above align environment at top of page/minipage

Tags: spacing, align

It seems that the `align` environment adds additional vertical space if it starts at the top of a page or `minipage`.  Below are two pages, and two `minipage`s (on Page 1), where the first page/`minipage` has text followed by an `align*` environment, and the second page/`minipage` starts with an `align*` environment, and note that the equations are still aligned.

[image]

### Attempted Solution:

The closest related question I found was:

- [Extra space above boxed multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18431/extra-space-above-boxed-multi-line-equation)

I attempted to use the [solution by Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18434/4301) at the above by adding `\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}` (after the preamble as per [Vertical space before and after align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/vertical-space-before-and-after-align-environment)).  Although, this did move the equations up vertically, they were still vertically aligned:

[image]

And since the problem occurs at top of a page as well, I don't think this is related to [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top)

### Question:

1. How can I adjust the `align` environment to automagically not have additional space at the top of a page or `minipage`?
2. Is there a reason for this behavior, and perhaps should not be changed?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=3.5in,paperheight=2.2in,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}%\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
Top of Page 1
\begin{align*}% Text above at top of page
 e &= m c^2
\end{align*}

\hrule
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    Top of minipage 1
    \begin{align*}% Text above this minipage
     e &= m c^2
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{align*}% No text above in this minipage
     e &= m c^2
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\newpage
\begin{align*}% No text above at top of page
 e &= m c^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you add `\topskip0pt` at the preamble the issue goes away.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: That seems to only change the spacing above the text at the top of the page, and has no effect on the spacing above the align environment.

Comment: Peter I am sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Related Question: [How do I suppress the whitespace above an equation block at the page top?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81658/how-do-i-suppress-the-whitespace-above-an-equation-block-at-the-page-top).

Comment: Related Question: [Why does minipage have different top/bottom margins for math environments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209553/why-does-minipage-have-different-top-bottom-margins-for-math-environments).

Answer (score 15):

The alignment environments of **amsmath** are not designed to be at the start of a paragraph. While this can be acceptable in normal situations, this has bad effects when we use a `minipage` for typesetting an alignment at a reduced width.

The `minipage` problem can be solved by patching the `\start@align` command (and  also `\start@gather` and `\start@multline`) with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\start@align{%
  \if@minipage\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip\fi
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This exploits the fact that at the start of a `minipage` the conditional `\if@minipage` is true, but upon starting a paragraph it becomes false, so subsequent `align` environments in the same `minipage` won't be affected.

There is a similar patch for "curing" the environments at start-of-paragraph, but I'm somewhat reluctant to show it, as I believe that a paragraph should *never* start with a displayed equation (with the above mentioned exception).

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for a `minipage`, as long as it is not at the top of a page (in which case it shifts the equation too far up). And while I agree that in a normal document one should _not_ start a page with a displayed equation, most of the time I am producing a single page which is composed entirely of a `\begin{align}...\end{align}` with a few `\shortintertext` in-between so would like to eliminate that space.