# How do I suppress the whitespace above an equation block at the page top?

Tags: spacing, equations, page-breaking

How do I suppress the whitespace above the equation block at the page top ?
It is added to the top margin, and I don't want that to happen.
I know that `\abovedisplayshortskip` controls this for the whole document, but how can I change this for this particular equation block and NOT for any others ?
Negative `vspace` doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper,english,dutch,leqno]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1.5cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}        
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\abovedisplayskip=6pt
\abovedisplayshortskip=3pt % This should NOT be changed
\belowdisplayskip=6pt
\belowdisplayshortskip=3pt

\begin{equation*}
\left.\begin{array}{r}
a_{31}'=a_{11}\cdot a_{31}-a_{31}\cdot a_{11}=0\\
a_{32}'=a_{11}\cdot a_{32}-a_{31}\cdot a_{12}\\
a_{33}'=a_{11}\cdot a_{33}-a_{31}\cdot a_{13}\\
a_{34}'=a_{11}\cdot a_{34}-a_{31}\cdot a_{14}\\
b_{3}'=a_{11}\cdot b_{3}-a_{31}\cdot b_{1}
\end{array}\!\!\right\}
\Longrightarrow\;
\begin{matrix*}[l]
\text{Pseudo-code :}\\
a_{11}\cdot b_{3}-a_{31}\cdot b_{1}\mapsto b_{3}\text{.}\\
\forall\;i\in\{4,3,2,1\} : a_{11}\cdot a_{3i}-a_{31}\cdot a_{1i}\mapsto a_{3i}\text{.} \end{matrix*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the problem is that you need to move the display to the next page, add `\pagebreak` at the end of the text that precedes the display. The space will automatically disappear.

Comment: It is strongly discouraged to start a page with displayed formulas.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not a skip that you have above the equation but a one line paragraph consisting of an indentation box and parfillskip glue. TeX display math environments do not generally react well to starting a paragraph they are designed to work mid-paragraph. If you need to do this you need to suppress the paragraph start with

```
\noindent
\begin{equation*}
```

and you will see the equation move up the page.

Comment: Works with `multline` too.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use equation with `{split}` inside, `\noindent` will not help you, because equation will appear a little higher then top of page. Add **showframe** option to geometry package and put this code in your document:

```
\clearpage
\noindent
\[
\begin{split}
\left(a^{B^{B^{B}}}\right)
\\
bb
\end{split}
\]
```

Here is a solution which helped me [How to place amsmath equations at top of page ignoring \topskip?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267972/how-to-place-amsmath-equations-at-top-of-page-ignoring-topskip)