# How to place amsmath equations at top of page ignoring \topskip?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, page-breaking, amsmath, tex-core

I need every amsmath equation to place at the top of the page. So I use `\noindent` to do that. Everything is fine except equation+split environment. Than formula is placed a bit higher (by `\vskip-\lineskiplimit` (it's -3pt) from asmmath.sty `\@display@init` macro). align+split is ok. The glue is discardable item but it's in a box so it's not discarded.

```
....\glue(\topskip) 0.0
....\hbox(21.00012+16.0001)x430.00462, direction TLT
.....\vbox(21.00012+16.0001)x430.00462, direction TLT
......\glue -3.0
......\glue 0.0
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\[
\begin{split}
\left(a^{B^{B^{B}}}\right)
\\
bb
\end{split}
\]

\clearpage
\noindent
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\left(a^{B^{B^{B}}}\right)
\\
bb
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to test am I on the top of page? Then I could fix that `\vskip`. I tried leaders but its very tricky.
2. Is there an other way to place formulas forcing `\topskip`?

Comment: I'm not sure what `\noindent` has to do with this... Do I miss something?

Comment: @yo' it stops the white paragraph line being formed before the display (but not if it is followed by `\par`  as in the second example.

Comment: it's generally considered bad form to start a page with a display.  `amsmath` was built around the assumption that (at least one) line of text would precede a display.  but, as the answer by david shows, the problem here is actually in the input.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is

```
\noindent

\begin{align}
```

you have a paragraph break there. Remove the blank line. The space at the top of the page is not dropped as it is not vertical space it is a one line blank paragraph.

With blank line before equation:

[image]

Without blank line:

[image]

With the corrected version and the addition of

```
\showoutput
\showboxdepth5
```

The log (using lualatex as you did) shows

```
....\glue(\topskip) 0.0
....\hbox(22.50012+17.5001)x199.16841, direction TLT
.....\glue(\tabskip) 80.22015
.....\hbox(22.50012+17.5001)x0.0, direction TLT []
```

Showing there is nothing on the page before the alignment.

Comment: David, with align I have no problem. Yes, that's my mistake that blank line in example. Actually I use \appto\mathdisplay@push{\parshape=\z@\par\noindent} I fixed example.

Comment: @Linuxss I can only answer as here. The \showoutput log you show does not seem to be from your example (before or after the rogue par is corrected) I get nothing between \topskip and the alignment box itself I will add the log to my question in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to use leaders to test am I on the top of page? What do experts think? Previously I tried check `\pagegoal`, `\maxdimen` and `\pagetotal`, but it worked not 100%.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
%% leaders should be discarded at top of new page
\newif\if@top@of@page\@top@of@pagefalse
  \def\check@top@of{%
    \ifmmode
    \else
      \@top@of@pagetrue
      \ifvmode
        \cleaders\vbox to \z@{\@top@of@pagefalse}\vskip\z@
      \else
        \cleaders\vbox to \z@{\@top@of@pagefalse}\hskip\z@
      \fi
    \fi
    }
%% Passing check to equations
\preto\equation{\check@top@of}
\expandafter\preto\csname equation*\endcsname{\check@top@of}

\def\@display@init#1{%
    \global\dt@ptrue \spread@equation
    \everycr{%
        \noalign{%
            #1%
            \ifdt@p
                \global\dt@pfalse
                %% No negative skip if equation is on a top of the page
                \if@top@of@page
                \else
                  \vskip-\lineskiplimit
                  \vskip\normallineskiplimit
                \fi
            \else
                \penalty\@eqpen \global\dspbrk@lvl\m@ne
            \fi
        }%
    }%
  }
%% don't add \topskip for equation 
\appto\mathdisplay@push{\noindent}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
\left(a^{B^{B^{B}}}\right)
\\
bb
\end{split}
\]

\clearpage
\noindent
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\left(a^{B^{B^{B}}}\right)
\\
bb
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I've fixed my problem with this code so I wrote it as an answer.