# Added vertical space on first page if starting with an equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Consider this simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is all fine. But if I start the document with an equation, then there is some added vertical space. Does anyone know what is causing this? I'm guessing there is some `\vskip` command in a .cls file where this is being defined?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\text{Hello world}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/spurious-space-above-align-environment-at-top-of-page-minipage

Comment: @nox Thanks, actually I think I've found the answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267972/how-to-place-amsmath-equations-at-top-of-page-ignoring-topskip. If I insert `\noindent`, the vertical space goes away.

Comment: Still not entirely sure where this vertical space originates from though. And how is it being defined?

Comment: From my observation, it doesn't make a difference for the positioning of the equation whether you put some text in the first line or skip it and print the equation. Maybe the equation is set in a `\vbox` that shifts down due to the indentation?

Comment: Informally speaking, without `\noindent` you get an empty line (10pt high), then 10pt of space (from `\abovedisplayskip`), then the “Hello world” text; with `\noindent` the first two are omitted.