# Placing a tikzpicture next to an align

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, minipage, multicol, wrapfigure

I have a `tikzpicture` with an accompanying explanation in a math `align` environment.  The `tikzpicture` is small enough that I'd like the explanation to appear next to (specifically, to the right) the `tikzpicture`.  Here's the code that I have:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(3,4) node [right] {$\bar{u}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(5,0) node [below] {$\bar{v}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(0,4) node [left] {$\bar{w}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(3,0) node [below] {$Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u}$};
\draw [dashed] (3,0) --(3,4);
\draw [thin] (2.5,0) --(2.5,.5) --(3,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{align*}
Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} &= \frac{\langle\bar{u},\bar{v}\rangle}{\langle\bar{v},\bar{v}\rangle}\bar{v} = \lambda\bar{v} \\
\bar{w}+Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} &= \bar{u}\\
\bar{w} &= \bar{u}-Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} \\
\bar{w} &= \bar{u}-\lambda\bar{v}
\end{align*}
```

I attempted to use `minipage`, `multicols`, and `wrapfig` but none produced a desirable result.  This was probably due to user error since I'm pretty new at this.

It'd be helpful if someone were able to produce something close to a standard to solve this problem (if one exists).

[image]

Comment: Meta: No, you would have to render it yourself and upload an image. [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272) Oh, and [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: May be you can [show us this way](https://www.writelatex.com/79721xndvzk)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No need to add thanks in your post, simply upvote any good answers you may receive. We try to keep posts concise this way.

Comment: I added the image and removed the meta question about that. Hope that is ok.  And for future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a _fully compilable_ [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why `minipage` did not work for you:

[image]

### Note:

- Perhaps your issue was with the excess vertical space at the top of the `align` in the minipage. Well that can be fixed with the solution from [Spurious space above align environment at top of page/minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/spurious-space-above-align-environment-at-top-of-page-minipage).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/spurious-space-above-align-environment-at-top-of-page-minipage
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\start@align{%
  \if@minipage\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip\fi
}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(3,4) node [right] {$\bar{u}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(5,0) node [below] {$\bar{v}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(0,4) node [left] {$\bar{w}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(3,0) node [below] {$Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u}$};
\draw [dashed] (3,0) --(3,4);
\draw [thin] (2.5,0) --(2.5,.5) --(3,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} &= \frac{\langle\bar{u},\bar{v}\rangle}{\langle\bar{v},\bar{v}\rangle}\bar{v} = \lambda\bar{v} \\
\bar{w}+Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} &= \bar{u}\\
\bar{w} &= \bar{u}-Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} \\
\bar{w} &= \bar{u}-\lambda\bar{v}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

---

Another option is to place the picture within a `varwidth` environment which has the advantage that you only need to tweak the size of the minipage containing the `align` which allows you to control how far the math content is.

[image]

### Notes:

- Even though the `varwidth` environment has a length specification, the box will adjust to the natural width of its contents.
- You could or course use the `varwidth` for the math content as well, but then you don't have as much flexibility to move the math content closer to the picture (unless you use an environment different spacing than the default `align`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz, varwidth}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/spurious-space-above-align-environment-at-top-of-page-minipage
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\start@align{%
  \if@minipage\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip\fi
}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(3,4) node [right] {$\bar{u}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(5,0) node [below] {$\bar{v}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(0,4) node [left] {$\bar{w}$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) --(3,0) node [below] {$Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u}$};
\draw [dashed] (3,0) --(3,4);
\draw [thin] (2.5,0) --(2.5,.5) --(3,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{varwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} &= \frac{\langle\bar{u},\bar{v}\rangle}{\langle\bar{v},\bar{v}\rangle}\bar{v} = \lambda\bar{v} \\
\bar{w}+Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} &= \bar{u}\\
\bar{w} &= \bar{u}-Pr_{\bar{v}}\bar{u} \\
\bar{w} &= \bar{u}-\lambda\bar{v}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```