# `gather` Environment Does Not Work with `minipage`

Tags: environments, minipage, width, varwidth

I have been using `minipage` environment with displayed equation environments `align*` and `gather*`. The `align*` environment works fine with `minipage` but does not work well with `varwidth`.

Code1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{varwidth}   

\begin{document}
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.002\linewidth}
\begin{align*}          
4x(x-5)&=0\\
4x=0\text{ or }x-5&=0\\
x=0\text{ or }x&=5.
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Output1:

[image]

Code2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{varwidth}   

\begin{document}
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.002\linewidth}
\begin{align*}          
4x(x-5)&=0\\
4x=0\text{ or }x-5&=0\\
x=0\text{ or }x&=5.
\end{align*}
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}
```

Output2:

[image]

> Note that, this `0.002\linewidth` is supposed to be the minimum width.

The same problem happens when using `gather*` with either `varwidth` or `minipage`. Besides, the centering of the equation lines is messed up.

Code3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{varwidth}   

\begin{document}
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.002\linewidth}
\begin{gather*}         
4x(x-5)=0\\
4x=0\text{ or }x-5=0\\
x=0\text{ or }x=5.
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Code4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{varwidth}   

\begin{document}
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.002\linewidth}
\begin{gather*}         
4x(x-5)=0\\
4x=0\text{ or }x-5=0\\
x=0\text{ or }x=5.
\end{gather*}
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}
```

Outputs 3 and 4:

[image]

I can use the `minipage` since it's working with the `align*` environment. But I'd still need to have the `gather*` environment fixed.

I'm using LuaLaTeX output mode.

Please advise. :)

Comment: Why do t you just use empheq? It has features build in to enable you to add frames around math, even allows eq numbers. Though, your question is interesting.

Comment: I tried using `empheq`, it works fine with both `align*` and `gather*`. But the package conflicts with other packages I'm using.

Comment: It would be great if there is a way to use `empheq` without loading `mathtools` with it.

Comment: I think you should probably change the title to say gather doesn't work with varwidth. I just looked at this (as current maintainer of amsmath) to see if there was a bug in gather, but it is working in minipage exactly as expected, centered in a box the size of the minipage (or overfull if that box is too small)

Comment: Why don't you want to load `mathtools`? It's ‘only’ a very useful extension of `amsmath`.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Spurious space above align environment at top of page/minipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954) (applies to all multi-line display environments defined by `amsmath`.)

Answer (score 3):

The way `gather` is implemented makes it it impossible for `varwidth` to correctly guess its “real” dimensions.

You can do by using the inline version, `gathered`, which doesn't even need `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
  $\begin{gathered}
  4x(x-5)=0\\
  4x=0\text{ or }x-5=0\\
  x=0\text{ or }x=5.
  \end{gathered}$%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]