# Aligning equations with gather with long equation tags in a minipage

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I would like to put two equations under each other, center aligned with `gather`. To complicate the matter, I would need two columns of such equations, thus I enclosed them in a `minipage`. [This is prone to some problems...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360447/gather-environment-does-not-work-with-minipage) The equations do not quite get aligned:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Make the equation fit on the page.
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\subtype}{\mathrel{<:}}
\newcommand*{\subtypeDep}{\mathrel{<:_{\textrm{dep}}}}
\newcommand*{\subtypePt}{\mathrel{<:_{\textrm{pt}}}}
\newcommand*{\lit}{\texttt}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{gather}
    \tau \subtype \tau \text, \tag{\textsc{S-Refl}} \\
    \frac{
      \delta_1 \subtypeDep \delta_2 \quad \rho_1 \subtypePt \rho_2
    }{
      \delta_1\,\rho_1 \subtype \delta_2\,\rho_2
    } \text, \tag{\textsc{S-Var}}
  \end{gather}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{align}
    \delta &\subtypeDep \delta \text, \tag{\textsc{SD-Refl}} \\
    \lit{const} &\subtypeDep \lit{marking} \text, \tag{\textsc{SD-Marking}} \\
    \rho &\subtypePt \rho \text, \tag{\textsc{SPt-Relf}} \\
    \lit{int} &\subtypePt \lit{double} \tag{\textsc{SPt-Double}}
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Is there any possible workaround for the deficiencies of `varwidth`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. both equation are centered. To see, what is going wrong at you, please provide complete small document -- MWE -- which will show your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I managed to isolate the problem properly. Truth is, this looks quite like a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360447/gather-environment-does-not-work-with-minipage now (with the twist the the suggested workaround to use `gathered` is not really applicable in my case, I think).

Comment: width of `minipage` is to small for properly working of `gather`. If you increase it to `0.6\textwidth`, you will obtain desired result.

Comment: At least judging by my eyes, there seems to be sufficient space to lay out the equations properly. Is there some length or other parameter I could change for that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top equation in the left box is centered in the allotted space; the bottom one, however, is too wide and would clash with the tag, so it's moved left.

You can use `eqparbox` for this, making the top equation as wide as the bottom one.

The first argument to `\matheqmakebox` is an arbitrary (but unique) tag.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Make the equation fit on the page.
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\subtype}{\mathrel{<:}}
\newcommand*{\subtypeDep}{\mathrel{<:_{\textrm{dep}}}}
\newcommand*{\subtypePt}{\mathrel{<:_{\textrm{pt}}}}
\newcommand*{\lit}{\texttt}

\newcommand{\matheqmakebox}[2]{%
  \eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle{#2}$}%
}

\begin{document}

\fboxrule=0.1pt
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{gather}
    \matheqmakebox{A}{
      \tau \subtype \tau,
    }
    \tag{\textsc{S-Refl}} \\
    \matheqmakebox{A}{
      \frac{
        \delta_1 \subtypeDep \delta_2 \quad \rho_1 \subtypePt \rho_2
      }{
        \delta_1\,\rho_1 \subtype \delta_2\,\rho_2
      },}
    \tag{\textsc{S-Var}}
  \end{gather}
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{align}
    \delta &\subtypeDep \delta \text, \tag{\textsc{SD-Refl}} \\
    \lit{const} &\subtypeDep \lit{marking} \text, \tag{\textsc{SD-Marking}} \\
    \rho &\subtypePt \rho \text, \tag{\textsc{SPt-Relf}} \\
    \lit{int} &\subtypePt \lit{double} \tag{\textsc{SPt-Double}}
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I used `\fbox` just to show the box boundaries.

[image]

Just for completeness, here is another example without boxes.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather}
short \tag{widetag} \\
lllllloooooonnnggg\tag{widetag}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]