# Weird gap within box if I type equation instead of text

Tags: equations, pdftex, lyx, margins, box

On Lyx, if I type an equation like this

[image]

then I get this on pdf

[image]

I mean, there is a huge gap within the box above the equation.

But if I type a non-equation text like this

[image]

then it's normal on pdf.

[image]

How can I remove that gap when I type equation within the box?

And here is the tex code that I used to generate it.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% this default might be overridden by plain title style
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{% 
\insertslidenavigationsymbol \insertframenavigationsymbol 
\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol \insertsectionnavigationsymbol 
\insertdocnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol \hspace{1em}% 
\usebeamerfont{footline} \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber% 
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{center}
{\small{}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\columnwidth}%
{\small{}
\begin{align*}
 & equation
\end{align*}
}%
\end{minipage}}{\small\par}
\par\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item Content
\item Content
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{center}
{\small{}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\columnwidth}%
\begin{center}
non-equation text
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}}{\small\par}
\par\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item Content
\item Content
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can reproduce in LyX, but I don't know the answer. It's usually recommended to provide the LaTeX so that the experts around here who don't use LyX can take a look. To do that, go to File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex) or whichever flavor you prefer, and post the contents of the resulting .tex file. By the way, nice clear question with screenshots! -> +1

Comment: @scottkosty  Thank you so much. I added tex.

Comment: @WillieWong  Thank you very much for your tip. I added the entire tex code now.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)

Comment: @barbarabeeton It does seem related. But I can't understand where to put which code into my tex code. Where should I put `\pretocmd\start@align` in my code? Where should I put `\if@minipage\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip\fi` ? And what are those `{}{}` ?

Comment: The block of code that begins `\usepackage{etoolbox}` would be placed in your preamble, exactly as it appears.  This should be the equivalent of inserting this at the top of a minipage that begins with an `align`: `\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip`; but of course that would have to be put into every minipage that starts with an `align`.  (This "direct" approach would be needed if the minipage begins with `equation` or a display that isn't based on `align`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Thank you! It does remove the gap. But actually too much perhaps. Now it looks like http://prntscr.com/rd3r9z.  Is there a way to adjust the margin?

Comment: I've finally had a chance to test it.  Forget the `\kern-\topskip`.  You need only the `\kern-\abovedisplayskip`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  This worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)
addresses this problem, the advice there isn't perfect.

The suggestion is to apply this spacing adjustment before the display that begins a minipage:
`\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip`.
But this is the result (shortening the example in the present question to the absolute minimum):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} %[t]{Title}                                                       
\centering
{\small{}}%                                                                     
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\columnwidth}%                                     
\kern-\topskip \kern-\abovedisplayskip
{\small{}
\begin{align*}
 & equation
\end{align*}
}%                                                                              
\end{minipage}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

The proper adjustment is to remove the `\topskip` adjustment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} %[t]{Title}                                                       
\centering
{\small{}}%                                                                     
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\columnwidth}%                                     
\kern-\abovedisplayskip
{\small{}
\begin{align*}
 & equation
\end{align*}
}%                                                                              
\end{minipage}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image]

The function of `\topskip` is by default to establish the vertical position of the baseline of the first line on a page.  That doesn't apply when a page begins with a math display.

Comment: I do not understand a sense of the `{\small{}}` in OP code. Isn't it better to dropout it (and by this remove clutter in code)?

Comment: @Zarko -- I agree that `{\small{}}` doesn't make sense (to me), but after trying the example without it, and finding that it did make a slight difference in the appearance, I decided to leave it in.

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\columnwidth}%
\kern-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{gather*}
  c_1^2 = a_1^2 + b_1^2
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Content
\item Content
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\columnwidth}%
\centering
non-equation text
\end{minipage}}
 \end{center}
   \begin{itemize}
\item Content
\item Content
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
` gives me the same result

Comment: @Zarko -- What do you mean by "the same result"?  The space above the display material is slightly larger than the space between the bottom of that and the end of the `\fbox`, but not the very large gap shown in the original question.  (Determining why those two spaces aren't the same will require some serious debugging, which I will try to do, but not immediately.)

Comment: In comment I just like to show code for comparison. When I compare result, i didn't observe difference between solution, which contains `{\small{}}` and which not. Well, my observation is subjective  since didn't made any (objective) measurement . About reason for difference in spaces I agree with you,