# How to display inline LaTeX code inside a LaTeX document?

Tags: verbatim

Is it possible in LaTeX to display inlined LaTeX code? I would like to write a CheatSheet and show side by side Equations and the code inside a tabularx environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%This works
\begin{verbatim}
$x^y\cdot\frac{1}{2}$
\end{verbatim}
%This does not work
\VERB{$x^y\cdot\frac{1}{2}$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you use wrong command name, instead of `\VERB{...}` should be `\verb{...}`. For selecting verbatim delimiter you should be careful, it should not be part of text in verbatim.

Your MWE, considering aforemntioned works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This works 
\begin{verbatim}
$x^y\cdot\frac{1}{2}$
\end{verbatim}

And this also work if you use correct command name:
\verb+B{$x^y\cdot\frac{1}{2}$+
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I normally use the package [`showexpl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/showexpl?lang=en) (which sits on top of [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
    This is a LaTeX example side by side
    \begin{LTXexample}[varwidth=true, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily]
        \[
            \int_a^b c\,dt
        \]
    \end{LTXexample}
    or below
    \begin{LTXexample}[pos=t, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily]
        \[
            \int_a^b c\,dt
        \]
    \end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's highly configurable via all the options available for `listings`.

Comment: There shouldn't be extra space at the top of the boxed displays.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954 for an explanation and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the complexity of using `showexpl` as in Rmano's answer, you can just use `listings` alone (although for demonstrating examples and code together it's fantastic). I usually combine it with `fancyvrb` which makes inline code simple to write also.  Here's just one  possible setup, which I use in documenting my own packages `listings`, but is highly configurable so you can choose a format that suits you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
  
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    frame=single
    captionpos=t
    language=TeX
}

\begin{document}

It's useful to have a simple inline code markup like |\bfseries|.

For larger pieces of code use |{lstlisting}|:

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
  
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    frame=single
    captionpos=t
    language=TeX
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]