# Do not move text to next page when formula does not fit in previous page

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, formulas

Whenever a formula does not fit in a mage, it is moved to the next as expected. However, the last line of text before the formula is moved in the same page as the formula, even though it would fit in the previous page. What command can I use to instruct Latex to move only the formula to the next page?

[image]

---

I have tried simply putting the formula in a new paragraph, but this adds a blank space that I do not want (see this picture). I would want a global solution that automatically implements the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: In traditional math publishing, placing a display at the top of a page without any text preceding it is considered bad style.  The display is considered part of the paragraph, regardless of the visual appearance; therefore the line of the paragraph preceding the display is brought over to a page that would otherwise begin with a display, regardless of whether it would fit on the previous page.  Regarding the space above a display at the top of a page, see [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TeXBook says:

> Plain TeX  sets `\predisplaypenalty=10000`, because fine
> printers traditionally shun displayed formulas at the very top of a page.
> You can change `\predisplaypenalty` and
> `\postdisplaypenalty` if you want to encourage or discourage
> page breaks just before or just after a display.

The same applies in LaTeX

Answer (score 3):

You can set `\displaywidowpenalty=10000`. This penalty is inserted before the last line of the paragraph immediately preceding a displayed equation.

Comment: unless you also lower predisplaypenalty this will prevent a single line by forcing two lines at top of the page, the question asks to go the other way and allow no line above the display