# Remove the spacing above align environment within fbox

Tags: spacing, formatting

I am trying to format solutions for an exam paper. [image]

Is it possible to remove the padding from the top?
The environment this is written in is:

```
\newenvironment{answer}[1]{%
\begin{solutionordottedlines}[#1]
\begin{minipage}[t][#1]{\textwidth}
}{%
\end{minipage}\end{solutionordottedlines}}
```

And my code is:

```
\part[1] initial vertical velocity $\vec{u}_{y}$ of the ball
% 1 mark: case one/two calculation and why
% 1 mark: the implication of them being equal
\begin{answer}{2cm}%

\begin{align*}
    \vec{v}_{y}&=\vec{u}_{y}+\vec{a}_{y}t\\
    0&=\vec{u}_{y}-9.8\times2.5\\
    \therefore \vec{u}_{y} &= 9.8\times2.5 = \SI{25.5}{\metre\per\second}\;\text{up}
\end{align*}
\end{answer}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code fragments into a small example we can compile please? What document class and packages are you using etc, we can't help without more information. Try adding `%` comments at the end of the lines in your first fragment, that may help (after `\begin{solutionordottedlines}[#1]%` and `\begin{minipage}[t][#1]{\textwidth}%`)

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm using the exam package (which to my knowledge is an extension of the article package but for exams).

Comment: I think I've figured out a way to balnce out the whitespace at the start of the box but it seems there is a large amount of whitespace at the bottom using the following:
```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
```

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{mathtools}` with the tag  ``\SwapAboveDisplaySkip`

Comment: This should answer your question: [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)

Comment: It does, thank you!